# Python - writing multiple lists to file

Tags: python, list, io

I'm trying to write my output to a new file. The required output is 4 rows with n number of columns. It works fine when printing in the terminal, however as soon as I try to write the output to a file, it all prints on one line.

This is the code that I have which works until I print to file. I have no idea why the output isn't the same. Can anyone explain why it is different please and how can I go about correcting this? (sorry i'm a newbie so simple terms would be helpful!) Any help is appreciated thanks!

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as p:
pwm = f.readlines()
lis=[x.split() for x in pwm]
for x in zip(*lis):
    pwm = "\t".join(x)
    print str(pwm) # this prints in required format
    p.write(str(pwm)) # this prints all on one line
```

Required output:

```
0.224   0.128   0.536   0.009   0.007   0.085   0.013   0.097   0.058
0.339   0.152   0.136   0.002   0.002   0.009   0.876   0.031   0.829
0.250   0.421   0.299   0.004   0.065   0.845   0.027   0.834   0.007   
0.186   0.299   0.029   0.985   0.926   0.061   0.084   0.038   0.106
```

File output:

```
    0.224   0.128   0.536   0.009   0.007   0.085   0.013   0.097   0.058    0.339  0.152   0.136   0.002   0.002   0.009   0.876   0.031   0.829 etc...
```

Comment: `write` doesn't implicitly add a newline, `print` does.

Comment: Add a `p.write('\n')` after you write pwm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `write` method of a file object just adds text to the end of the file.  If you want to have each row on its own line, you need to add a newline to the end of the string:

```
p.write(str(pwm) + "\n")
```

You do not have to do this with `print` because it does this for you implicitly.

Comment: Thank you it worked and now I understand why that happens! I will accept your answer when it lets me :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the following:

```
p.writelines(str(pwm))
```

Comment: You can also write multiple lines to a file using this function.

Answer (score 0):

You can either write a newline explicitly or use `print` with a file redirection.

```
p.write(str(pwm) + "\n")

print >> p, pwm
```